# Do TDEE estimates consider calories lost via pooping?

Tags: bulking

I'm bulking on 3500 kcals as per  TDEE calculator

I sh^t a lot after my meals. My weight has unfortunately *decreased*, though my strength is the same. I suspect it's because of the crazy sh^ts. Is there a way to validate this?

Put another way, is there a way you've lost a significant number of calories from shi^tting?  (Do I need to do it in a bucket and take it to a lab to figure out how many calories I've lost?)

Comment: How much % above your maintenance calories is that? Be aware that the more you eat, the more you crap...

Answer (score 4):

Leaving aside the possibility of foods incompletely digesting due to overconsumption or quirks of your intestines, most of what you excrete is waste product, things you cannot get nutrition from, so you effectively are losing no calories, as the calculations for kilocalories for nutritional labels on foods are required to be for digestible calories (mild caveat that the current Atwater method, based off of the amount of protein, carbohydrate, fat and alcohol in the product, has been criticized for that it assumes complete digestion, which means that 500 calories of processed food provides less energy than 500 calories of raw food). Still, the difference is relatively minor.

Comment: Bulking is all about overconsumption though, right? Bigger meals. How do you distinguish between sh^ts with nutritional content that was meant to absorbed vs sh^ts with no calories?

Comment: Hmm... that's getting a little outside my area of knowledge. I personally can tell that I have undigested food by smell, but I also have a peculiarly strong sense of smell in a lot ways. It might indeed require a chemical analysis to find what amount was absorbed.